# Is $Cov(A,BA)$ equal to $Var(A)E(B)$ when $A$ is a vector and $B$ is a matrix?

Tags: matrices, covariance

I have a square matrix $B_{nxn}$ and a vector $A_{nx1}$ where $B$ and $A$ are independent with each other. I solved $Cov(A,BA)$ and obtained $Var(A)E(B)$ as follows,

$Cov(A,BA)=E(A^2)E(B)-E(A)(E(A)E(R))$

$=[E(A^2)-(E(A))^2]E(B)$

$=Var(A)E(B)$

$Var(A)$ will result in a scalar value. But, $B$ is a matrix. So, the result just not justify enough for $Cov(A,BA)$ which is a scalar value.

Please be kind enough to provide any instruction on the mistake I have made.

If $Var(A)E(B)$ is not correct, how can $Cov(A,BA)$ be solved and what is the answer for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we are dealing with vectors and matrices, we must be careful with operations like squares and so on. The calculation would go like this I think:

\begin{eqnarray*}Cov(A,BA)&=&E[(A-E[A])(BA-E[BA])^T]\\
&=&E[(A-E[A])(B(A-E[A]))^T]\\
&=&E[(A-E[A])(A-E[A])^TB^T]\\
&=&Cov(A)E[B]^T\end{eqnarray*}

Here $Cov(A)$ is the covariance matrix of the vector $A$, which corresponds to $Var(A)$. So the result is basically what you expected, but we need to respect matrix rules.

Comment: Thanks.. In my case, $Var(A)=1$ because vector A is Z-Score normalised. So, $Cov(A)=1$. Then $Cov(A,BA)=E[B]^T$ will be incorrect. What should I do for that?

Comment: No, $Var(A)$ cannot be a number. It is a matrix.

Comment: But, $A$ is a vector of $nx1$. So, $Var(A)$ is a number, isn't it?

Comment: No, it's not. Imagine $n=2$. Then $A_1$ and $A_2$ both have an own scalar variance and they have a covariance. All this information is stored in a $2\times 2$ matrix. (Entry $(i,i)$ being $Var(A_i)$ and entry $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ being $Cov(A_1,A_2)$).

Comment: In a standardised situation where each entry of $A$ has variance 1 and the entries are independent, we have $Cov(A)=\mathbb{I}_n$. (Identity matrix). Then the result would be $Cov(A,BA)=E[B]^T$

Comment: Yes, that's the specific situation I was dealing with. Now, that the $Cov(A,BA)$ is $E[B]^T$, I'm struggling to come up with a proper way of determining $E[B]^T$.

Is there any specific way of determinng $E[B]^T$ in the form of trace, determinant?

Comment: Most of the time the expectation is not too difficult since it's entrywise. Do you know the expectation (or the distribution) of the individual entries $B_{ij}$? Then $E[B]^T$ is just the transpose of the matrix that has these expectations as entries.
I don't think that trace/determinant can tell you much here.

Comment: In my case $B$ is a rotational matrix with an incremental angle of theta (I have the control of the angle). So, what should I consider as the expectation of that matrix?

Comment: Well, I'm not really familiar with general rotational matrices - you mean that in your case there is basically only one random variable, the angle $\theta$? What is the distribution of this angle?